# delete windows certificate from powershell or cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-command-prompt

[image: SEE IMAGE]

I want to delete all my PERSONAL certificates from  certmgr.msc from command line , is this possible?
I tried some code but it doesnt work
I can list my certificates by runing this in powershell

```
dir cert:\\CurrentUser\My\
```

I tried this but is not working

```
PS C:\Users\A\Desktop> rm cert:\\CurrentUser\My\0B909E44056411513E2B220007541AF4822B5C10
Remove-Item : Provider execution stopped because the provider does not  support this operation.
At line:1 char:3
+ rm <<<<  cert:\\CurrentUser\My\0B909E44056411513E2B220007541AF4822B5C10
+ CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [Remove-Item], PSNotSupportedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupported,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Answer (score 3):

What OS and PowerShell version are you on? Your `rm cert:\\CurrentUser\My\thumbprint` example works on my machine.

The other way I would do it is via the pipeline. But ultimately, it's the same thing using `Remove-Item`.

```
gci cert:\CurrentUser\My | Remove-Item
```

The [`Remove-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/providers/remove-item-for-certificate?view=powershell-6) documentation indicates the ability to use it against certificates was added in PowerShell version 3.0.